# angular 2 router index.html sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010, angular2-routing

I have a angular 2 SPA running from within a SharePoint 2010 document library. However, I have a problem with routing. When I start the application by running "index.html", the link in the browser shortly displays:

```
<server>/scripts/angular_app/index.html
```

When the application is loaded it changes to:

```
<server>/scripts/angular_app/#/information-system
```

'information-system' is the default route of my application.
So far, so good.
If I do a reload of the page now, SharePoint loads its default view:

```
<server>/scripts/angular_app/Forms/AllItems.aspx
```

This is because the routing removes the 'Index.html' from the url and SharePoint loads the default which is 'AllItems.aspx' and not 'index.html'.

Is there any way of telling the angular 2 routing system to leave the 'index.html' bit in the url?

Thanks for any help!

Joachim

Answer (score 1):

I added following line to index.html to keep index.html in the URL all the time:

```
<base href="/index.html">
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by extending the base href with the filename at compile time:

```
ng build --dev --bh /scripts/filingangular/index.html
```

I was not aware that you could put an actual filename here.